# Don't understand binary format

Tags: ruby, cryptography, padding, encryption

I have to encrypt a message with a "zero padding" in OpenSSL.
I have read here ([Use Zero Padding in OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087155/use-zero-padding-in-openssl)) that if I want a "zero padding", I have to add myself the 0. So here we go.

I'm trying to pad the "A" message for exemple. But there is one thing I don't understand.

```
   ["a"].pack("b*").each_byte { |b| printf("%08b", b) }
   => "00000000"
   ["c"].pack("b*").each_byte { |b| printf("%08b", b) }
   => "00000000"
```

Why the results are equal ? "a" and "c" are 2 differents strings, but the binary is equal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pack` has a directive for zero-padding:

```
["a"].pack("a2") 
#=> "a\x00"`
```

As for your question, you want to unpack a string, not pack an array:

```
'a'.unpack('b*')
#=> ["10000110"]
'c'.unpack('b*')
#=> ["11000110"]
```

Comment: Can you also explain why the code within the question does not work? I've been looking at it for a few minutes now but since I'm not a Ruby programmer, I just don't get it.

Comment: yes, you' right ! I have to unpack the string. Thanks